# How to read from a file and put the elements by grouping as 3 into a doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I have a file that I need to read when the program starts running and then I need to put each 3 chars into a node in a doubly linked list. I started by reading from the file but I cannot take each element as char and put into the doubly linked list. I wrote this but Im stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int i;
    string myText;
    
    ifstream MyReadFile("example.txt");
    
    while(MyReadFile>>noskipws>>myText){
        cout<<myText
        
    }
    
    MyReadFile.close();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to write more code before asking or redefine your question to the part of this assignment that you have attempted. Since there is nothing in the code about linked lists  you probably want to remove that part from the question.

Comment: you cannot put them in a linked list, because there is no linked list in your code. Would `std::list` be ok ?

Comment: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Another question to ask is: what is going to be the type of object that you put into the list? A `struct` containing three `char`? An array of three `char`?

Comment: Note that `>>` operator will take input from file till space is reached. So, if you want to read char, as you mentioned, you will need to change the implementation accordingly.

Comment: How much do you know about linked lists? Did you follow tutorials? Did you do something simpler, like putting simple `int`s into the nodes of double-linked list?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
struct Three_chars
{
    char a, b, c;
};
 
char a;
char b;
char c;
std::list<Three_chars> database;
while (MyReadFile >> noskipws >> a >> b >> c)
{
    Three_chars triple;
    triple.a = a;
    triple.b = b;
    triple.c = c;
    database.push_back(triple);
}
```

The above code declares `Three_chars` as a *node* containing three characters.
The `while` expression reads in 3 characters into character variables.
The `while` loop creates a node, copies the 3 characters read, into the *node*, then appends the node to the linked list.